# How to access fetch data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to access data inside then() method.

```
var dataset;
fetch ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDPdata.json').then (response=>response.json()).then(val=>{

dataset=JSON.stringify(val.data)
});
```

When i console out it outside then() method it give me this:

```
undefined;
```

But when I try to console it out inside , it give me my desired result;
I just want to store my desired result in my dataset variable. How?

Comment: do something like this (simplified code) var data = fetch.....then(return data)

Comment: define dataset first using keywork like `var,let,const `